# Calculation script to find average based on other columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, average

I have a Google Sheet that is being used to track applicant interview data. I am trying to find the Round Average Score for each candidate based on their Interview Round and Round score. I figured out how to gather this data with a query function but for this use case in particular it has to be done in a script.

[Here is an example of the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13pgyihLO3mwLHPfwO05sL8dxj032XYRnxPC0kO0cSNo/edit?usp=sharing)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It is unclear _why_ you would need to use a script. Consider showing your _manually entered_ desired results in the sample spreadsheet, and explain what your end goal is.

Comment: Why not just use AverageIfs? `=AVERAGEIFS(E:E,A:A,A2,C:C,C2)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Average of Average Scores

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let co = { pA: [] }
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let p = `${r[0]}/${r[2]}`;
    if (!co.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      co[p] = { cnt: 1, sum: r[4], idx: i }
      co.pA.push(p);
    } else {
      co[p].cnt += 1;
      co[p].sum += r[4];
    }
  });
  let vo = vs.map((r, i) => {
    let p = `${r[0]}/${r[2]}`;
    if (i == co[p].idx) {
      return [co[p].sum / co[p].cnt];
    } else {
      return [''];
    }
  })
  sh.getRange(2, 6, vo.length, vo[0].length).setValues(vo);
}
```

Ouput:

| Candidate | Position | Interview Round | Panelist | Round Score | Round Average Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Tester | First | Jon | 3 | 4 |
| Bob | Tester | First | Janet | 4 |  |
| Bob | Tester | First | Joe | 5 |  |
| Bob | Tester | Second | Sal | 4 | 3.333333333 |
| Bob | Tester | Second | Riley | 3 |  |
| Bob | Tester | Second | Tae | 3 |  |
| Bob | Tester | Final | Wanda | 5 | 4.666666667 |
| Bob | Tester | Final | Kelly | 4 |  |
| Bob | Tester | Final | Arnold | 5 |  |
| Al | Senior Tester | First | Ben | 2 | 3 |
| Al | Senior Tester | First | Tori | 3 |  |
| Al | Senior Tester | First | Harry | 4 |  |
| Al | Senior Tester | Second | Kate | 4 | 3.666666667 |
| Al | Senior Tester | Second | Wendy | 5 |  |
| Al | Senior Tester | Second | Carl | 2 |  |
| Al | Senior Tester | Final | Sam | 5 | 4 |
| Al | Senior Tester | Final | Jake | 3 |  |
| Al | Senior Tester | Final | Troy | 4 |  |

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the data as permanent static values that will not change later even if the source data gets modified, you can still use a `query()` formula to get the results, and then use a short script to replace the formula and its results with static values. To try it out, **Insert > Sheet** and use this:

`=query(sumAve!A1:E, "select A, B, avg(D) where D is not null group by A, B", 1)`

```
/**
* Replaces formulas with values in the active sheet.
*/
function replaceFormulasWithValuesInActiveSheet() {
  const wholeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  wholeSheet.setValues(wholeSheet.getValues());
}
```